# group_concat mysql comma separated field

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have the following subquery:

```
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tb5403_matrix_header.tb5403_name_ru) 
    FROM tb5403_matrix_header 
    WHERE tb5403_matrix_header.tb5403_id IN 
 (tb0201_tb5403_ids) 
    GROUP BY tb5403_matrix_header.tb5403_id
```

The field `tb0201_tb5403_ids` contains numbers separated with commas: 
10, 2, 4
5, 8, 7 and so on.
However, mysql is selecting only the first element of the field:
10
5

Any help guys!

Comment: Share your sample input data table

Comment: @KMS this is the full query: `SELECT tb0001_user.tb0001_name1, tb0001_user.tb0001_name2, 

(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tb5403_matrix_header.tb5403_name_ru) FROM tb5403_matrix_header WHERE tb5403_matrix_header.tb5403_id IN 
 (tb0201_tb5403_ids) GROUP BY tb5403_matrix_header.tb5403_id)

FROM tb0201_student 
INNER JOIN tb0001_user ON tb0201_tb0001_id=tb0001_user.tb0001_id
INNER JOIN tb0012_class ON tb0001_user.tb0001_tb0012_id=tb0012_class.tb0012_id

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hk42nn8dgguug7p/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Edit your question to provide full query. It's hard to read full query in comment section. And.. Provide table structure,data and desired result.

Comment: The [`IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) function doesn't work this way. It expects a list of values between parentheses and it compares the expression before `IN` against all the values between parentheses. You have only one value between parentheses: the string stored in the `tb0201_tb5403_ids` column. MySQL is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment by axiac - try [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tb5403_matrix_header.tb5403_name_ru) 
FROM tb5403_matrix_header 
WHERE 
FIND_IN_SET(tb5403_matrix_header.tb5403_id, tb0201_tb5403_ids) != 0
GROUP BY tb5403_matrix_header.tb5403_id
```